# select the date from ms access in dd.mm.yyyy format

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I want to select the data from the database using select command
but the result is showing in yy.mm.dd format 
while i want the result in dd mm yy format 
I am using the following commad

```
  select  date from table1 order by date desc;
```

how can i get the date in dd mm yyyy format please help me

Comment: SQL queries should return the data in raw form. It should be your business or presentation levels that do the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to user [format function for date](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php).

`select format([date], "dd.mm.yyyy") from table1 order by [date] desc;`

Comment: i am using this in java and its showing as wrong field name few parameters expected one

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid date as a field Name, since it is a reserved word.

```
select  Format([date],"dd/mm/yyyy") as Dt from table1 order by [date] desc;
```

My feeling is that you should conserve the field as a date until the very end, and just render it in the final form/report/whatever. Using Format() will change it to a string and it will not sort or add properly anymore. In Access, for instance, one would leave is as it is and rather modify the Format property of the Control bound to that field. Since you tagged your question with [Java], I can't tell you more...

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the question.